# Wordpress jquery wont work (Calculation System)

Tags: javascript

Hi i can't get the jquery script to work and i can't find out why.
Would be awesome if someone could help me out on this one have tryed plugins and other things and it just wont work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title> Checkbox Summation </title>
<style type="text/css">
 .cbValue { }
</style>
<body>

<div id="CostBox">
<input type="checkbox" class="cbValue" value="9.99"  onclick="UpdateCost()">Product 1 ( 9.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cbValue" value="19.99" onclick="UpdateCost()">Product 2 (19.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cbValue" value="27.50" onclick="UpdateCost()">Product 3 (27.50)<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cbValue" value="45.65" onclick="UpdateCost()">Product 4 (45.65)<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cbValue" value="87.20" onclick="UpdateCost()">Product 5 (87.20)<br>
<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="" size="6"> Total ($)
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function UpdateCost() {
  var sum = 0;
  var sel = document.getElementById('CostBox').getElementsByClassName('cbValue');
  for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
    if (sel[i].checked) { sum += Number(sel[i].value); }
  }
  document.getElementById('totalcost').value = sum.toFixed(2);
} 


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's just a JavaScript function not jquery.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066537/calculate-total-value-checkboxes-jquery), I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Your code works in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eg4XR/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any jQuery code on your page.
Are you getting any errors? 
Does the jQuery source exist at files/jquery-1.8.1.js?

You could try loading jQuery from a CDN to be sure:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
```

also, try adding something simple like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("jQuery Running");
});
```