# jQuery sum checkbox values

Tags: jquery, checkbox, input

I'd need to calculate sum of all checkboxes and update total based on selection here is html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="basic_single" name="basic_single" value="400">
<input type="checkbox" id="basic_double" name="basic_double" value="680">
.
.
.
<input type="text" name="total" value="" size="30" id="total">
```

here is the script

```
   $('input:checkbox').change(function ()
     {
      var total = 0;
      var basic_single = parseInt($('#basic_single:checked').val());
      var basic_double = parseInt($('#basic_double:checked').val());

      var total = basic_single + basic_double;

      $("#total").val(total);

    });
```

if both are checked it works fine, but just one checked returns NaN,
there will be more checkboxes than just these two

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066537/calculate-total-value-checkboxes-jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to consider only the items which are checked to calculate the total. For this, you can only target the elements which are checked and iterate through each loop to add their values to calculate the sum. Following example involves no hardcoding of individual elements.

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function ()
{
      var total = 0;
      $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){ // iterate through each checked element.
        total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
      });     
      $("#total").val(total);

});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/8p3ftmuh/2/

Comment: @BenyBondBanjarnahor: I don't know what your html looks like so can't help without knowing it. Create a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.not()` to exclude `#total` element value from calculations, `.get()` , `Array.prototype.reduce()` , `+` operator to cast `value` of `:checkbox` to `Number`

```js
$(":checkbox").change(function(event) {
  $("#total").val(function() {
    return $(event.target.tagName).not("[type=text]")
    .get().reduce(function(a, b) {
        return +a.value + +b.value
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="basic_single" name="basic_single" value="400">
<input type="checkbox" id="basic_double" name="basic_double" value="680">
<input type="text" name="total" value="" size="30" id="total">
```