# Interactive checkbox in PHP

Tags: php

I need an interactive checkbox in php, where I select the checkboxes I want to pay for and will update the "Valor Base[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7shG.png)" field as soon as I select or deselect the checkbox

code:

```
<?php require_once("banco-contrato.php"); ?>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container" >
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <form name="form" action="lista-contrato.php" method="post">
            <p>Código do Cliente: <input type="text" name="cliente" id="cliente" required autofocus placeholder="Código do cliente"></p>
            <p>Data Pagamento:<input type="date" name="dp" id="dp" required></p>
            <p>Taxa :<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" max="10" name="tx" id="tx" required placeholder="Taxa de juros"></p>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="formulario">Calcular</button></td>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



<body>
    <?php 
    $valorTotal = 0;
    if  ( isset($_POST\["formulario"\])) {    
        $cliente = isset($_POST\['cliente'\]) ? $_POST\['cliente'\] : "";
        $dp = isset($_POST\['dp'\]) ? $_POST\['dp'\] : date("Ymd");
        $tx = isset($_POST\['tx'\]) ? $_POST\['tx'\] : "Você esqueceu a taxa";
        $contratos = buscaContrato($conexao, $cliente, $dp); ?>                

        <div class="table-responsive" style="float:left;">
            <table class="table  table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Selecione</th>
                    <th scope="col">Contrato</th>
                    <th scope="col">Parcela</th>
                    <th scope="col">Valor da Parcela</th>
                    <th scope="col">Vencimento</th>
                    <th scope="col">Dias Atrasados</th>
                    <th scope="col">Multiplicador</th>
                    <th scope="col">Valor atual</th>
                </tr>
                <?php                        
                foreach ($contratos as $contrato ) :
                    $multiplicador = round(calculaJuros($contrato\['Atrs'\], $tx), 4);
                    $valorAtual = round(($multiplicador * str_replace(",","",($contrato\['valorParcela'\]))/100), 2); 
                                         // para que a multiplicação de certo tem que remover a virgula utilizando o str_replace e resultado dividir por 100. 
                    $valorTotal = $valorAtual + $valorTotal;

                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="parc" id="parc"></td>
                        <td><?= $contrato\['contrato'\] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $contrato\['parcela'\] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $contrato\['valorParcela'\] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $contrato\['vencto'\] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $contrato\['Atrs'\] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $multiplicador ?></td>
                        <td><?= round($valorAtual, 2) ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                endforeach
                ?>
            </table>
        </div> 
        <form name="form" action="lista-contrato.php" method="post">
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="formulario">Calcular</button></td>
        </form>               
    <?php } ?>

    <?php 
    if ( isset($_POST\['dp'\])){ ?>
        <div class="table-responsive" style="float:left;">
            <table class="table  table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Dados Parcelamento</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Data Pagamento</th>
                    <td><?= date("d/m/Y", strtotime($_POST\['dp'\])) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Taxa Mensal</th>
                    <td> 5,95 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Valor base</th>
                    <td><?= $valorTotal ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Parcelas</th>
                    <td>
                      <select name="numeroDeParcelas">
                          <option value="1">1x</option>
                          <option value="2">2x</option>
                          <option value="3">3x</option>
                          <option value="4">4x</option>
                          <option value="5">5x</option>
                          <option value="6">6x</option>
                          <option value="7">7x</option>
                          <option value="8">8x</option>
                          <option value="9">9x</option>
                          <option value="10">10x</option>
                          <option value="11">11x</option>
                          <option value="12">12x</option>
                      </select> 
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js" ></script>
  <script>
      $( function)
  </script>
</body>][1]
```

Could someone help me?

how do I update this "valor base" field automatically whenever any checkbox is selected or deselected?

Comment: Sorry, PHP runs on the server. There's no way to execute it in the visitor's browser after the page was sent. Your only chance is JavaScript (which you seem to be using already anyway).

Answer (score 0):

As @Alvaro-gonzalez says, PHP works on server side so you must need to send a post or reload the page every time user clicks on a checkbox, this is time consuming and not effective, so you could use jQuery, or JavaScript or something you're comfortable to achieve this. You also can populate a hidden input if you need to post the result value later.

[You can see similar case here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136351/jquery-sum-checkbox-values)