# To sum value of span and one select tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get value of one or more span and just one select tag and get thus the sum and display it in 'total' row when submitting.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1wZA.png) . Final aim is to have the sum of items when selected. I added screenshot of my table.

Thanks in advance.

```
                if ($('#screen').is(":checked")) {
                        $('#screen_display').html($("#screen").val());
                        $('#price_screen').append("300"); 
                   
                    }
                if ($('#garantie').is(":checked")) {
                        $('#garantie_display').html($("#garantie").val());
                        $('#price_garantie').append("200"); 
                    }
                 if ($('#printer').is(":checked")) {
                        $('#printer_display').html($("#printer").val());
                        $('#price_printer').append("100"); 
                    }
                 if ($('#mouse').is(":checked")) {
                        $('#mouse_display').html($("#mouse").val());
                        $('#price_mouse).append("40"); 
                    }
```

```
               <select id="select_price" required>
                    <option value="">Please select price</option>
                    <option value="799" class="price" >799</option>
                    <option value="500" class="price" >500</option>
                    <option value="1200"class="price" >1200</option>
                    <option value="1500"class="price" >1500</option>
                </select>
           
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="screen" value = "screen"/>
                    <label for="screen">screen :</label><span id="300" class="price"> 300</span><br>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="garantie" value="garantie"/>
                    <label for="garantie">Garantie :</label><span id="200" class="price" >200</span><br>
                </div>
  <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="printer" value="printer"/>
                    <label for="printer">Printer :</label><span id="100" class="price" >100</span><br>
                </div>
               <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="mouse" value="mouse"/>
                <label for="mouse">Mouse fil :</label><span id="40" class="price" >40</span><br><br>
               </div>
```

I finalise my project

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: I tried so many solutions to sum items selected but none works.

Comment: The code shown clearly has a syntax error, did you miss the error being reported on your browser's development console?  If you're not familiar with the development tools in your browser, now is a great time to start.  Correct any errors being reported, then step through the code in the script debugger as it executes and observe the results of each individual operation.  When you do that, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136351/jquery-sum-checkbox-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below should work, you can repeat the process for other span elements

```
var span1Value = parseInt($("#price_screen").text());    
var span2Value = parseInt($("#price_garantie").text());    
var selectValue = parseInt($("#select_price").find(":selected").val());    

var total = span1Value + span2Value + selectValue;
$('#total').html(total);
```

Comment: .price is a class selector it will give all elements that contain that class not a single element like querying with #

Comment: Thanks. I deleted .price in select tag because we use #select_price and kept  .price  in span tag.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjiKk.png)

@RickyGymmadi

I modified a little, because span class is '.price'. But result is weird

```
var span1Value = parseInt($(".price").text());      
var selectValue = parseInt($("#select_prix").find(":selected").val());    
var total = span1Value + selectValue;
```

Comment: your first line thete $(".prix") will return two element an array, you have two labels with prix class printer : and mouse fill

Comment: My bad.. It was in French and put it in English