# jQuery decimals not shown in result sum of checked boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below make the sum of the checked boxes and shows the result.

I've got this code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066537/calculate-total-value-checkboxes-jQuery)  question in stackoverflow.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" checked value="Gez" rel="69.95">Gezichtsbehandeling
<input type="checkbox" value="ExtraLang" rel="9.95">Extra lange 
<input type="checkbox" value="Massage" rel="59.95">Massage
<input type="checkbox" value="Pedicure" rel="35">Pedicure

Totaal <span id="output"></span>
```

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function recalculate() {
        var sum = 0;

        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
            ;
        });

        $("#output").html(sum);
    }

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
    });
});

</script>
```

Problem is that the sum doesn't show decimals.

See here [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/richard7/efvxefx1/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per your JSFiddle:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).attr("rel"));
    });
```

change the `parseInt` to `parseFloat` to keep the decimal point.

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fthytwaL/)

**UPDATE:**

Per your request to get the output to be formatted to 2 decimal places.. you need to change

```
$("#output").html(sum);
```

To:

```
$("#output").html(sum.toFixed(2));
```

That should give you the the format you want.

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnf31wnz/)

Comment: ahh you are 15 secs earlier. +1 to you :)

Comment: @Sk.Tajbir haha thank you.  Great minds think alike :)

Comment: Just interesting, how is it better than [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37813590) approach? /cc @Richard

Comment: @Richard I have updated my answer to give you the format of 2 decimal places

Answer (score 2):

Obviously this is happening because parseInt is stripping the decimal part. Convert it to a any number, not specifically int.

```
sum += +$(this).attr("rel");
```

Comment: Your approach is prolly better, and simpler when you start. However in the code I had it was simply to change parseInt into parseFloat. I hope this answers your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).attr("rel"));
});
```

Replace parseInt to parseFloat. Here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/efvxefx1/2/

Thanks.

Comment: Thank this works good too,   to bad you were a little slower, Thank you anyway for the effort. +1

Answer (score 2):

get sum two digit after the decimal as well!

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).attr("rel"));
        });
     sum = sum.toFixed(2)
   $("#output").html(sum);
```

Comment: Thank you, the fixed decimals was something else I needed to know. It  Works perfect

Comment: Upvote for formatting the `sum` to 2 decimal places :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are converting it to Int before doing sum. Please update your code to below one-

```
sum += parseFloat($(this).attr("rel"));
```