# I need to update total value after checking every checkbox (if they check and uncheck) I need to get the old value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend, laravel-6

I don't want to submit anything, just display the value, like a calculator I was searching around and I found out that I can do it using jquery, but number never work for me (so if you guys can recommend me something easier). On the last field I want to display the total value times 27. In this example I am trying to multiply by 10 every time we click on a checkbox, and at the end multiply the total by 27.

```
 <div class="fields">
    <div class="fields radio_label_top">
      <fieldset>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="sameAddress"  value="freight" id="freight"> Freight  $0.0</label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="sameAddress"  value="insurance" id="insurance"> Insurance $0.00</label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="sameAddress"  value="duty" id="duty"> Duty $0.00</label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="sameAddress"  value="vat" id="vat"> VAT $0.00</label>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="fields ">
   <div class="fields result">
     <label>The ﬁels above show in USD currency</label>
     <div class="dfield fields column2">
     <input name="usdTotal" class="field large" type="text" value="1" id="usdTotal" placeholder='$ USD'>
    </div>
</div>



This is my script



 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#freight").click(function(){

                if($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                    $("#usdTotal").text(function(i, origText) {
                        localStorage['oldValue'] = origText;
                        return (+origText + ((origText * 10)));
                    });
                } else{
                    $("#usdTotal").text(function(){
                        return localStorage.oldValue;
                    });
                }
            });
            $("#insurance").click(function(){

                if($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                    $("#usdTotal").text(function(i, origText) {
                        localStorage['oldValue'] = origText;
                        return (+origText + ((origText * 10)));
                    });
                } else{
                    $("#usdTotal").text(function(){
                        return localStorage.oldValue;
                    });
                }
            });
            $("#duty").click(function(){

                if($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                    $("#usdTotal").text(function(i, origText) {
                        localStorage['oldValue'] = origText;
                        return (+origText + ((origText * 10)));
                    });
                } else{
                    $("#usdTotal").text(function(){
                        return localStorage.oldValue;
                    });
                }
            });
            $("#vat").click(function() {

                if($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                    $("#usdTotal").text(function(i, origText) {
                        localStorage.oldValue = origText;
                        return (+origText + ((origText * 10)));
                    });
                } else{
                    $("#usdTotal").text(function() {
                        return localStorage.oldValue;
                    });
                }
            });
            $("#usdTotal").change(function() {
                $("#ttdTotal").text(function(i, origText) {
                    return (+origText * 27 );
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.fields>.fields.radio_label_top'), boxesLength = boxes.length;  function allChecked(){  let n = 0; for(let i=0; i<boxesLength; i++){ if(boxes[i].checked)n++; } if(n === boxesLength){ return true; } return false; }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calculate total value checkboxes jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066537/calculate-total-value-checkboxes-jquery)